# Windows Live Mail client caused all my Network Solutions email to be deleted?

Tags: email, pop3, windows-live-mail

I was downloading my mail from Network Solutions' server via POP on Windows Live Mail. The download failed halfway through, so I deleted the emails via Windows Live Mail. When I went back to the browser to the Network Solutions webmail interface, all my emails in the inbox were gone!

I thought POP doesn't sync the mail client with the server- how is it possible that all my mail is gone?

Answer (score 4):

POP doesn't sync, but usually all emails you download are then deleted from the server, as you can see e.g. [in this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol#Dialog_example). Some email clients let you disable that behavior, but it's likely that by default it's enabled.

Windows Live Mail deleted the emails from the server, and you deleted the downloaded copies from Windows Live Mail on your local machine.